# Python quiz- how to accept mostly correct answers

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that allows a user to set up personal quizzes (like a notecard-type system). When taking the quiz, the user is timed on each question. The answers aren't going to be multiple choice though, they will be user-inputted.

Is there a way that I can sufficiently accept answers that aren't complete answers of the input they put in when they first set up their quiz?

#### Example

Q: "Who is Socrates."

A:  "A Greek Philosopher."

---

I thought about using something like:

```
if input in answer:
    print "That's correct."
```

But that doesn't work at all.

Is there any possible way to do this? Or something close to it.

---update---

I just recently came across a Python Module that is outstanding at doing this, it's called FuzzyWuzzy and here is a link to it's description and what all it can do http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python

Comment: You're going to have to use natural language processing or fuzzy matching to compare the answers.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know the term fuzzy matching before but after a quick search it seems that there is already a Levenshtein module, and another module that claims to be a bit quicker called Jellyfish if anyone else is interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do. Your attempt sounds like you are trying to match any substring of "A Greek Philosopher", so "ee" would be a correct answer. That doesn't sound right.

You could have a set (or list) of possible correct answers for each question. For your example maybe you would also accept just "Philosopher".

If you would like to ignore spelling mistakes, you could test if what was entered is "close" to any of the know correct answers. This requires a function that will calculate how close the match is. A popular approach is to use Levenshtein Distance. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576874-levenshtein-distance/
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

#### Update

Levenshtein Distance is good if you want to allow inexact spelling. But if you want to allow different phrases, i.e. "A Philosopher from Ancient Greece" then a different approach is required. If you're really motivated, you could try to use [NLTK, Natural Language Toolkit for Python](http://nltk.org/) to implement a type of fuzzy phrase matching where you try to match parts of speech rather then the exact phrase provided. Be aware, this is **not trivial**.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem with that is that users will be inputting the answers so I can't really build a list unless I had them do it. 
The links you provided look interesting though, so thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the question author would provide a set of answers. How else would you do it? (Unless you have IBM's Watson and it's not busy winning Jeopardy.)

Comment: It depends what you mean by `this`. The exact requirements of the original question were not clear. If you mean ignore simple spelling mistakes, or maybe leaving out small connecting words, then yes. But I was talking about phrase variations, re-ordering the words, maybe having different but related words. Levenshtien is not a good choice for that.

Comment: The NLTK toolkit looks awesome, if I try developing this app that I'm making for more than just myself I'll definitely look into this. Thank you.